# Vanilla JS, Add and Remove on Class on Scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Hey i am trying to add a class depending on the scroll position.
It worked in Jquery but i want to move to vanilla, it doesn't work.
What am i missing?

IF the User scrolls to position 30px it should add the class .c-logo--scrolled

Console Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at add_class_on_scroll (app.min.js:17)
    at app.min.js:29

```
var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
var logoContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('js-logo');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPosition >= 30) {
        logoContainer.classList.add('c-logo--scrolled');
    } else {
        logoContainer.classList.remove('c-logo--scrolled');
    }

});
```

Comment: i just removed the . ...but somehow it says :Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at add_class_on_scroll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> var logoContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('js-logo');
> ```

```
var logoContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('js-logo')[0];
```

Then:

1. Place your scripts in the bottom of the body.
2. Ensure what element is really scrolling - it's not always window.
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY - no support in IE
4. http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist - partial support in IE10+

Comment: ahhh that worked ...why do i have to add the [0], so isnt it safe to use window ? is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Karle, because `getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList. But you are using `classList` which is a property of element, not of the list. `scrollY` seems to be not supported in IE (added a link to the answer), also element could depend on css.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot , i will use pageYOffset instead...thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Karle, if it solved your problec, accept an answer by clicking checkmark on the left of it.